# Saving into $_SESSION without direct interaction

Tags: php, ajax, session

I have a table and its `<td>` elements contain `input` fields:

```php
<td>
    <input type='text' id='field001'>
</td>
```

Now, I am looking for a way to store the *value*, which I am typing into the `input` field,  right into `$_SESSION` variables. And this without any direct user interaction. So, without any `submit` or `onClick()` events.

The user should be able to visit the other pages on the website without loosing the information typed into the table previously.
I guess using AJAX there must be a way to accomplish this task, but I don't know how to trigger an event when the input field has new text (and especially without user interaction)?

Imagine a Excel workbook with two sheets. *Sheet 1* is a table to be filled out, and *sheet 2* contains some further information. In Excel (obviously) you can switch between the sheets without loosing the input in your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save your input value to a database table every 5 secs or store  it like a PHP $_SESSION using ajax.

```
$("#field001").keyup( function(){
var timer ;
   clearInterval(timer);//reset timer while typing
   var text = $(this).val();//grab input box text

   timer = setInterval(function(){

   $("#feedback").text("Saving...");
   //ajax post to php page
   $.post("save_data_page.php",{text:text},function(){
   $("#feedback").text("");});

   },5000);//save text every 5 secs
})
```

in your "save_data_page.php", use the code:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
session_start();//start a session
}

if(isset($_POST['text'])){
  //create a session variable called typed_text01
  $_SESSION['typed_text01']=$_POST['text'];
}
?>
```

In your input box you can echo out the stored session value as shown below

```
<input id="field001" val="<?php echo $_SESSION['typed_text01']; ?>" />
```

Comment: thx Udy for your detailed answer and the great `code comments`! :-) I do not understand the `$("#feedback")` part entirely. Where can I find id=feedback in the HTML or is generated?

Comment: $("#feedback") is just a div you can add to your page to see when ever the ajax is saving your text.
e.g

<div id="feedback"></div>

Can be added below your input box

Comment: Oh, great! Basically something like `console.log()`... Other question: `{text:text}` On an abstract way I understand what this is doing but I am just a bit confused. The first `text:`, to what is it referring? And the second `text`,  is it referring to the variable above?

Comment: @Lex  Its similar to something like `$text = $text` Or `$carrier=$text` `{carrier:text}`. You just need a carrier to pass your variable to the php page(Ajax rules). if I use `{carrier:text}` on my php page I will receive it as $_POST['carrier'].

Comment: You offered me a complete solution and great explanations! Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this I'd say is indeed the use of $_SESSION (or some equivalent user session concept in some framework) or the use of cookies. Cookies are in my opinion nastier, though some may say they could work well for what you're trying to accomplish.

In order to do  this without the user clicking anything specific or submitting any form, you'll have to figure out a way to always save the users input when he's done filling in something.

Thankfully, whenever a user is done filling in an input element, and clicks something else, the input loses *focus*. DOM elements have events that trigger when an input field gets, or loses focus if I'm not mistaken. You can easily register functions to these events using jQuery. When the lose-focus event triggers, you could send an Ajax request to your server containing the data the user just filled in, together with the id of the field the user interacted with.
There in your server you can store it in your $_SESSION variable (I believe after you call something like session_create()).

If the focus event doesn't satisfy your needs you'll have to find another way to trigger some ajax communication with your server, because there is no option of just making it happen obviously.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess using AJAX there must be a way to accomplish this task, but I don't know how to trigger an event when the input field has new text (and especially without user interaction)?

If you want to do it without user interaction, then use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).

If you want to do it when the input field has text text (which is when the user interacts with it to enter new text), then use an [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent) or [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, give me some time to acquaint myself with this handlers.